# Is there a "first" Fourier transform?

Tags: fft, terminology

Every time I've read "first Fourier transform", I've assumed it to be a misspelling of the fast Fourier transform. Recently though, I saw the term in both the title and keywords of an article from a seemingly serious, albeit not peer-reviewed, journal, Japanese Circulation Journal.

[*Development of a new analytical method for the electrocardiogram using short-time first Fourier transforms*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10614838) doesn't cite any resource or explain the algorithm. ([fulltext PDF](http://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jcj/63/12/941/_pdf))

Is there a "first" Fourier transform?

Comment: The article refers to fast Fourier transforms in the text (see Figure 3, for instance). So I assume this too is a mistake. Brings back fond memories of my first Fourier transform, written in Basic, and not fast.

Comment: @mtrw: That figure text is the _only_ mention of the fast FT (except for one reference), while the "first" FT is mentioned twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Independently of what they call it, the process described in the paper is *precisely* the Fast Fourier Transform. This is made obvious by the FFT algorithm they describe, including the Gold-Rader bit-reversal procedure.

On a side note, if one tries Googling "SFFT", the S in the acronym stands for anything from *sliding* to *spherical*, but the F's always stand for *Fast Fourier*.